# npm install electron error on rasberry pi 3

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, electron, raspberry-pi3

I am sorry about the format of pasted code.

I was trying to install MagicMirror and found out that I need to install electron, but I keep getting error.

I tried to install different version of node, but it didn't work. The below is what I got when I typed `npm install`.

> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ npm install electron
>
> (node:8786) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated.
>   Use os.tmpdir() instead.
>
> npm ERR! Error: Method Not Allowed
>
> npm ERR!     at errorResponse
>   (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache/add-named.js:260:10)
>
> npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/cache/add-named.js:203:12
>
> npm ERR!     at saved
>   (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:167:7)
>
> npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15)
>
> npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
>
> npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
>
> npm ERR!     http://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>
> npm ERR! System Linux 4.14.52-v7+
>
> npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "electron"
>
> npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
>
> npm ERR! node -v v8.11.1
>
> npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
>
> npm ERR! code E405
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     /home/pi/npm-debug.log
>
> npm ERR! not ok code 0 pi@raspberrypi:~ $

Answer (score 0):

Install the project and it's dependencies on your normal pc and build the electron application for the ARM (Raspberry Pi) architecture.
After you have built it get it in your Raspberry Pi and launch it.